# Closest string match with regular expression

Tags: regex, fuzzy-search

Is there a way to match an input word to a closest acceptable word according a regular expression, sort of like spell check/Google's "Did you mean: x?" except for regular expressions/finite automata? Are there any specific algorithms?

edit: programming in Java, but I'm more interested in if there's any algorithms that exist for this purpose.

Comment: What programming lanuage are you interested in?

Comment: Java, but I'm more interested if there's any actual algorithms that do this, or pseudo code is fine too.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). It calculates the difference/closeness of two words.

As a code example Python provides a [function in the difflib module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.get_close_matches) that you pass a string and a list of strings, it gives you back good matchings strings. 
So you might want to get a list of words starting with the same letter(s) as your word (from a database/file) and then check for the closeness of them.
Does this go into the direction you are interested in?

Comment: Yes it is and I was thinking about implementing it this way too using Levenshtein distance in the worst case if there were no existing algorithms that do the job, since it does seem a little time consuming listing out all the words and then comparing them...

Answer (score 1):

In general, no. Regular expressions are exact matching mechanisms. What you are looking for is more of a fuzzy matching.

Now, regular expressions can be constructed to match multiple alternatives. And some of those alternatives can represent common misspellings. For example:

```
r'potatoe?s?'
```

Would match `potato`, `potatoe`, `potatos`, and `potatoes`. But constructing all of the possible not-quite-right combinations is laborious and error-prone.

You would generally do much better to employ a fuzzy matching algorithm to judge the "closeness" of an entered term to a list of all known/appropriate terms. For example, in Python you can install and use the [fuzzywuzzy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fuzzywuzzy) module, which computes "closeness" using [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance):

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process

commands = ["open", "close", "run", "debug", "help" ]

for word in ["open", "closer", "runt", "defung", "xlkjs"]:
    choice, score = process.extractOne(word, commands)
    if score < 70:
        print "don't understand {0!r} {1}".format(word, score)
    else:
        print "correcting {0!r} to {1!r} (score {2})".format(word, choice, score)
```

Yielding:

```
correcting 'open' to 'open' (score 100)
correcting 'closer' to 'close' (score 91)
correcting 'runt' to 'run' (score 86)
correcting 'defung' to 'debug' (score 73)
don't understand 'xlkjs' 40
```

You can tweak your desired threshold at which you wish to determine "not close enough to consider it correctable."

**Update**

[@k-nut](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26694447/240490) makes the good suggestion of `difflib.get_close_matches(word, possibilities[, n][, cutoff])`. That has the virtue of being part of the standard library. Of course, if you're using a different language, you'll need to explore "find close match" libraries for that specific language.